# Deleting items from a list as a "trigger" for a while loop

Tags: python, list, while-loop

I want to do this:

```
while list:
    for blah in blah:
        things
    list.remove(min(list))
```

Would this loop until all the items in list are removed? As i have it my code, it just loops through [list] times, and then returns from the function. I need a loop that will keep going until all the items of list are gone.

I should note, nothing inbetween (in the for loop) is processed until the last iteration.

By request, the entire algorithm as it runs:

```
def parsexlsx(address):
    bits = [] 
    i = 0
    while address:
        min_address = False
        for row in ws.iter_rows(row_offset=4,column_offset=3):
            c = row[2]
            d = row[3]
            if not d.internal_value:
                if min_address:     #we set it to true, then kept going until blank row
                    break           #bits is what you want it to be now
                bits = []           #reset bits every time we hit a new row
                continue            #this will just skip to next row

            for bits_cell in row[4:]:
                if bits_cell.internal_value:
                    bits.append(bits_cell.internal_value)
            if c.internal_value:
                if c.internal_value == min(address):
                    min_address = True
        address.remove(min(address))

    print bits
    return bits
```

Comment: *it just loops through [list] times* and *I need a loop that will keep going until all the items of list are gone*. It does exactly that, what goes wrong? We need to see your original code..

Comment: @MartijnPieters i'll edit the original post with the whole thing.

Comment: and what is the exact problem then? Looks like it'd work just fine to me.

Comment: "nothing inbetween (in the for loop) is processed until the last iteration": could you show that?  If it only worked the *first* time, I'd've guessed that ws.iter_rows() was exhausting its source, but if you're right that it's the last one then it's something else related to what goes on inside the for loop and the `while/remove` bit is only a red herring.

Comment: it will only process the contents of the for loop on the last iteration of the loop. Say the highest number in address is 20, it will only process when it gets down to 20.

Comment: @DSM do you want the consol output? or...?

Comment: @ZakParks then it must be the logic within the most outer `for` loop, how do you know nothing happens, I don't see any print statements, also are you sure about this `for bits_cell in row[4:]` being that you've already set the offsets `ws.iter_rows(row_offset=4,column_offset=3)`

Comment: @ZakParks: no, you can do the debugging as well as any of us -- better, since you know what it's supposed to do.  What I'm suggesting is that the problem might be that your for loop isn't doing what you think it's doing.  Stick `print` statements everywhere inside the for loop to make sure that (1) it's really being executed, and (2) it's doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: @DSM yeah i'll do that, i've only been python-ing for 10 days so im rusty on this. Now that everyone said that my original question's logic was right, the issue is definately somewhere else. Thanks :)

Comment: @samy.vilar yeah, i probably said "nothing happens" prematurely. The issue is definately somewhere in that loop, i'll try and pick it out

Comment: @MartijnPieters oh yeah i know, i dont want to imply that I was asking for anyone would fix it. My original question of if the loop would work was answered, so im done here haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a separate variable from `bits` to hold EVERY piece of data. `bits` gets reset throughout your code, so I would recommend using something like `all_bits` and change `bits` to `min_addr_bits`. Also, you need to make sure for EVERY row that isn't blank, you append bits to `all_bits`. Example posted on request.

Comment: if you have something in mind im open to trying it out, i have been trying various things all morning to no avail using your advice here.

Answer (score 1):

What's the problem?

Your code should work

```
>>> l=[1,2]
>>> while l:
...     print l
...     l.remove(min(l))
... 
[1, 2]
[2]
```

Comment: yes, but nothing inbetween (in the for loop) is processed until the last iteration

Comment: @ZakParks: Then the issue must be in the usage of `ws.iter_rows(row_offset=4,column_offset=3)` or something else in the `for` loop.

Comment: That is possible, the for loop was written first, then wrapped with the aforementioned while loop, so im thinking that there was a problem before i knew there was a problem...

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for something like this?

```
while len(list) > 0:
    for blah in blah:
        things
    list.remove(min(list))
```

Comment: This should be completely equivalent to the original since if `bool(len(LL) > 0)` is equivalent to `bool(LL)` (if LL is a list, or tuple, or string for that matter...)

Comment: In Python, `bool(list) == False` when `len(list) == 0` and `True` otherwise, so his condition is perfectly fine.

Comment: Oh, I had no idea, pardon my mistake and thank you for the comments! Though I do believe that explicit is better than implicit ;) python pep 20 anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will, see the string `foobar` is printed 10 times,which is equal to length of A

```
>>> A=[1,1,2,3,3,3,4,5,6,6]
>>> while A:
     print('foobar')
     A.remove(min(A))


foobar
foobar
foobar
foobar
foobar
foobar
foobar
foobar
foobar
foobar
```